# Find the limit of this

Tags: limits

How would I compute the limit of a function such as this? $$\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{m}{((x+m)(g-1)-m(g-2))(1+x+m)-m^2}$$

I'm not sure what to divide by in this case as I would just get the limit of the numerator to be either $0$ or $\infty$. The solution should be :

$$\lim_{m\to \infty} f(m) = \frac{1}{1+gx}$$

I'm thinking to get to this, $f(m)$ should be simplified further.

Comment: Yes, please simplify the denominator of $f(m)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{m}{g m x + g x^2 + g x + m - x^2 - x}=\\=\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{1}{g  x + (g x^2)/m + (g x)/m + 1 - x^2/m - x/m}=\frac1{gx+1}$$

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to comment my answer - simplifying the denominator made it much more easy than it was meant to be by just dividing through by m...

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Compute the derivative of the denominator, call it $F(m)$:
\begin{align}
F(m)
&=(g-1-g+2)(1+x+m)+(x+m)(g-1)-m(g-2)-2m\\
&=1+x+x(g-1)+m(1+g-1-g+2-2)\\
&=1+xg
\end{align}
Now it's just l'Hôpital. Or, if you prefer, $F(m)=(1+xg)m+A$, for some constant term $A$, precisely
$$
A=F(0)=x(g-1)(1+x)
$$
but it's unimportant.